# Android create directory in external storage root

Tags: android, file, storage, external, root

i'm trying to create a directory in external storage **root**.

I can already write into the com.example.me.myapp directory, but i need to create a dir in external storage root, just as Whatsapp does

Is it possible ?

Thank's !

Comment: Yes. Possible of course. And what is it that that app does?.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. These apps (Facebook and Snapchat also does that) create a directory in root external storage folder to write files in this directory. I need to do the same, do you know how to do that ? @greenapps

Comment: Show your code to determine the external storage directory p!ease.